# Android CameraX Error retrieving camcorder profile params

Tags: android, android-camera, androidx, android-camerax

I am migrating to cameraX and faced the exception

```
androidx.camera.core.InitializationException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error retrieving camcorder profile params
```

The error-log states that this error is thrown when calling

```
            cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()
```

I cannot reproduce this error on any device.

I initialize the Camera here:

```
private fun initCameraProvider() {
    val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this) //Error is thrown here
    cameraProviderFuture.addListener(Runnable {
        cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()
        val metrics = DisplayMetrics().also {
            previewView?.display?.getRealMetrics(it) 
        }
        val screenAspectRatio = ImageUtils.aspectRatio(metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels)
        val rotation = previewView?.display?.rotation ?: 0

        preview = Preview.Builder()
                .setTargetAspectRatio(screenAspectRatio)
                .setTargetRotation(rotation)
                .build()
        analyzer = BarcodeAnalyzer(previewView, overlay) { onSuccess(it) }
        val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA

        imageAnalyzer = ImageAnalysis.Builder()
                .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
                .setTargetAspectRatio(screenAspectRatio)
                .build()
                .also {
                    it.setAnalyzer(cameraExecutor, analyzer)
                }


        val useCaseGroup = UseCaseGroup.Builder()
                .addUseCase(preview)
                .addUseCase(imageAnalyzer)
                .build()
        try {
            cameraProvider?.unbindAll()
            preview.setSurfaceProvider(previewView?.surfaceProvider)
            camera = cameraProvider?.bindToLifecycle(this, cameraSelector, useCaseGroup)
        } catch (exc: Exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Use case binding failed", exc)
        }


    }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this))
}
```

Comment: I've added the provided workaround to my answer, try it and see it works for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update: (24/03/2021 - dd/MM/yyyy)**

The bug has been fixed in CameraX [1.0.0-rc04](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/camera#1.0.0-rc04) and [1.0.0-alpha23](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/camera#extensions-view-1.0.0-alpha23).
Just update the dependencies to this version or above

---

**Update: (22/03/2021 - dd/MM/yyyy)**

There should be a new CameraX release soon which fixes the problem, in the mean time you can apply this workaround:

```
// CameraX core library
def camerax_version = '1.0.0-rc03'
implementation("androidx.camera:camera-core") {
    version {
        strictly "$camerax_version"
    }
    because "Force use 1.0.0-rc03"
}

// CameraX Camera2 extensions
implementation("androidx.camera:camera-camera2") {
    version {
        strictly "$camerax_version"
    }
    because "Force use 1.0.0-rc03"
}

// CameraX Lifecycle library
implementation("androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle") {
    version {
        strictly "$camerax_version"
    }
    because "Force use 1.0.0-rc03"
}
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-extensions:1.0.0-alpha22"
implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-alpha22'
```

as described [here](https://groups.google.com/a/android.com/g/camerax-developers/c/tknTsusj1X4/m/jXN1YVDaAQAJ)

---

Currently there is bug in CameraX affecting (at least) Samsung S20+ and Galaxy Note 10+

Here the issue link for updates: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/181599852

Comment: What's interesting is that both devices are not tested according to this source https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/devices

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue using camerax version 1.1.0-alpha01 on Samsung s20+ and note 10+. Try to downgrade to 1.0.0-beta11.

Comment: I've the same crash on Note 10+ with CameraX 1.0.0-rc03 (not tried 1.0.0-beta11 yet)

Comment: 1.0.0-beta11 is the latest stable version for my workaround, so i'll just stick with it for a while

Answer (score 0):

Change a cameraSelector.
Take a look the [link](https://github.com/android/camera-samples/blob/main/CameraXBasic/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/cameraxbasic/fragments/CameraFragment.kt).

```
lensFacing = when {
            hasBackCamera() -> CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK
            hasFrontCamera() -> CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_FRONT
            else -> throw IllegalStateException("Back and front camera are unavailable")
        }
val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.Builder().requireLensFacing(lensFacing).build()
```

And change the version like this:

```
def camerax_version = "1.0.0-rc01"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-core:${camerax_version}"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:${camerax_version}"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:${camerax_version}"
implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-alpha20'
implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-extensions:1.0.0-alpha20'
```